# Value of type 'name' has no dynamic member 'name' using key path from root type 'name'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am learning MVVM and applying it to a simple converter app. The problem arises when I try to pass the array into a picker with ForEach.
Here is my code:

Model:

```
struct UserOptions {
    var userOption = 0.0
    var userChoseInput = "Meters"
    var userChoseOutput = "Feets"
    var userUnits = ["Meters", "Kilometers", "Feets", "Yards"]
}
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var options = UserOptions()
var finalResult: Double {...calculations here...}
}
```

View:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@StateObject private var viewModel = RulerViewModel()

var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section {
            Picker("What is your input?", selection: $viewModel.userChoseInput) {
                ForEach($viewModel.userUnits, id: \.self) { _ in //Value of type 'ObservedObject<ViewModel>.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'userUnits' using key path from root type 'ViewModel'
                    Text($viewModel.userChoseOutput)  
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        } header: {
            Text("Choose your input")
        }
        .textCase(nil)
        
        
        Section {
            TextField("Your number", value: $viewModel.userOption, format: .number)
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                .focused($userValueIsFocused)
        }
        Section {
            Picker("What is your output?", selection: $viewModel.userChoseOutput) {
                ForEach($viewModel.userUnits, id: \.self) { _ in
                    Text(viewModel.userChoseOutput)  //Value of type 'ObservedObject<ViewModel>.Wrapper' has no dynamic member 'userUnits' using key path from root type 'ViewModel'
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$viewModel.options.userUnits
```

And

```
viewModel.options.userChoseOutput
```

As for your loop something like this would let you access the unique values

```
ForEach(viewModel.options.userUnits, id: \.self) { unit in
    Text(unit)
}
```

I suggest you also look into `Measurement` it will save you a lot of time when working with conversions.

Comment: When I add it, it runs into an error: Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Binding<String>' conform to 'StringProtocol'
How can I fix that?

Comment: @Ozzzie remove `$` to the beginning where you get that error.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience!
When I did as you said: 
`Picker("What is your input?", selection: $viewModel.options.userChoseInput) {
                    ForEach($viewModel.options.userUnits, id: \.self) { _ in
                        Text(viewModel.options.userChoseInput)
                    }`

 It ran me into an issue where all 4 options in picker are the same. When you choose "meters", three others become "meters" too. 
Any suggestions how can I fix that?

Comment: @Ozzzie that is what you are telling the view to display. See an update above I added an extra line `unit` will give you the unique values.

Comment: @Ozzzie if I answered your question can you mark the answer with the checkmark?